# Mapping IO[Either[String, User]] into IO[User] in scala

Tags: scala, io, mapping, endpoint, either

I have a data type that I want to map into another type in scala.

`val x = IO[Either[String, User]]` that I want to map into `IO[User]`.
I'm thinking of a way different than pattern matching a more optimized one. because I'm only interested in the case of Right projection.

( just to clarify this result would be mapped as Ok for the Endpoint response)

Comment: Well, what should happen if the result was a `Left`? - You probably want to lift that as an error so what you would do would be something like: `x.map(_.leftMap(msg => UserError(msg))).retrhow` were `UserError` is a class that extends from `Throwable`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez so the way to do it is mapping, the left and the right side of either in a way both are handled? What iif instead of having IO[Either[String, User]] I had EitherT[IO, String, USer]] is it easier to handle it into IO[User]

Comment: No `EitherT` won't help in any way AFAIK. You need to handle both cases, there are multiple ways to do that: consume both results, turn the error into a value, lift the error in the hidden channel of `IO`.

Comment: thanks alot @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: It would be slightly simpler with `EitherT[IO, String, User]`: `eitherT.leftMap(UserError(_)).rethrowT`